# How to form another colum in a pd.DataFrame out of different variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make a new boolean variable by an if-statement with multiple conditions in other variables. But so far my many tries do not even work with variable as parameter.

[head of used columns in data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NoCs.png)

I would really appreciate if anyone of you can see the Problem, I already searched for two days the whole World Wide Web. But as beginner I couldn't find the solution yet.

```py
amount = df4['AnzZahlungIDAD']
time = df4['DLZ_SCHDATSCHL']
Erstr = df4['Schadenwert']
Zahlges = df4['zahlgesbrut']
timequantil = time.quantile(.2)
diff = (Erstr-Zahlges)/Erstr*100
diffrange = [(diff <=15) & (diff >= -15)]
special = df4[['Taxatoreneinsatz', 'Belegpruefereinsatz_rel', 'IntSVKZ', 'ExtTechSVKZ']]
```

First Method with list comprehension

```py
label = []
label = [True if (amount[i] <= 1) & (time[i] <= timequantil) & (diff == diffrange) & (special == 'N') else False for i in label]
label
```

Second Method with iterrows()

```py
df4['label'] = pd.Series([])
df4['label'] = [True if (row[amount] <= 1) & (row[time] <= timequantil) & (row[diff] == diffrange) & (row[special] == 'N') else False for row in df4.iterrows()]
df4['label']
```

3rd Method with Lambda function

```
df4.loc[:,'label'] = '1'
df4['label'] = df4['label'].apply([lambda c: True if (c[amount] <= 1) & (c[time] <= timequantil) & (c[diff] == diffrange) & (c[special]) == 'N' else False for c in df4['label']], axis = 0)
df4['label'].value_counts()
```

I expected that I get a varialbe "Label" in my dataframe df4 that is whether True or False.

Fewer tries gave me only all values = False or all = True even if I used only a single Parameter, which is impossible by the data.

First Method runs fine but Outputs: []

Second Method gives me following error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not Series

Third Method does not load at all.

Comment: Would you like to shorten your questions with some sample data. It is hard to follow your questions now. I recommend you to generate a sample dataframe and tell us what you want to achieve and show the expected dataframe.

Comment: thanks for your Suggestion, I'll include head of the DataFrame

Comment: You have multiple columns for the 'special' column but you compare as you had only one. What is the logic you are after for using this values?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, they all have to be == 'N' if the new variable 'label' should be True. But if it is not possible that way I know I can solve by Splitting them in single ones. Sadly that is not the Problem here since even if I just chose any of the Parameters in my if Statements without the others, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try this

```
time = df4['DLZ_SCHDATSCHL']
Erstr = df4['Schadenwert']
Zahlges = df4['zahlgesbrut']
# timequantil = time.quantile(.2)
diff = (Erstr-Zahlges)/Erstr*100

df4['label'] = (df4['AnzZahlungIDAD'] <= 1) & (time <= time.quantile(.2)) & (diff <=15) & (diff >= -15) & (df['Belegpruefereinsatz_rel'] =='N') & (df['Taxatoreneinsatz'] =='N') & (df['ExtTechSVKZ'] =='N') & (df['IntSVKZ'] =='N')
```

Given your dataset i got following output

```
    Anz dlz sch zal taxa    bel int ext label
0   2   82  200 253.80  N   N   N   J   False
1   2   82  200 253.80  N   N   N   J   False
2   1   153 200 323.68  N   J   N   N   False
3   1   153 200 323.68  N   J   N   N   False
4   1   191 500 1252.12 N   J   N   N   False
```

Note: Don't mind the abbreviations used in column name

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked finally! I used to use this Solution before but without () and then drifted off to more complicated ones. Sometimes the easiest way is the best :)